# How to create new postgres user for a new Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I created a new rails project `rails new devise_gem_app -d postgresql` and changed `config/database.yml` to these:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  username: devise_gem_app
  password: devise_gem_app
  host: localhost

development:
  <<: *default
  database: devise_gem_app_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: devise_gem_app_test
```

But I don't know how to connect the user to this batabase

I create a user like this: `createuser devise_gem_app -W` set it as a super user and I set password to: devise_gem_app.

But when I try `rake db:migrate` I get:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "devise_gem_app"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "devise_gem_app"
```

I even chenged last line of `pg_hbf.conf` to:

```
#local   replication     postgres   trust
```

... and nothing ...

I know this should be easy but I just don't see what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the `createuser` command is doing, but you could always set the password for the `devise_gem_app` user directly in postgres.

```
ALTER user devise_gem_app WITH password 'devise_gem_app';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create user user_name with password 'password' createdb;
```

And in `pg_hbf.conf` file

```
#Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I ended following this tutorial: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-add-postgresql-user-account/

But I am upset that it seems rails don`t support, creating new users for new projects db, which seems to be common practice.